# Pandas shift() for taking previous value of column is not working in apply and np.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe and i want to create a new column on where condition.

```
id    Value   Flag  last_value
1     100      0       200
1     250      1       200
1     50       0       200
1     300      1       200
2     200      1       100
2     200      0       100
2     50       0       100
2     10       0       100
```

First i wanted to create a column as X where value for the first row of ids will be 1 such as

```
df['X'] = np.where(df.duplicated('id'),0,1)

id    Value   Flag   X   last_value
1     100      0     1    200
1     250      1     0    200
1     50       0     0    200
1     300      1     0    200
2     200      1     1    100
2     200      0     0    100
2     50       0     0    100
2     10       0     0    100
```

now i want a column 'High' with condition if X=1 and Flag=1 then High=Value,if X=0 and Flag=1 then High = Value,if X=1 and Flag=0 then High=last_value,if X=0 and Flag=0 then High = previous High i.e one row value above of present row.I used apply function and it works fine for first three condition but not for the 4th one which is X=0 and Flag=0 as i am using

```
elif (row['X'] == 0) &  (row['Flag'] == 0):
    return row['High'].shift()
```

It gives error as

```
Float has no attribute as 'shift'
```

So i used apply function for the first 3 condition and np.where for the 4th and still its not working.I want my answer as

```
id    Value   Flag   X     High  last_value
1     100      0     1     200      200
1     250      1     0     250      200
1     50       0     0     250      200
1     300      1     0     300      200
2     200      1     1     200      100
2     200      0     0     200      100
2     50       0     0     200      100
2     10       0     0     200      100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use np.select

Create boolean selection or condition

```
c1=(df["X"].isin([0,1] )& df['Flag']==1) 
c2=((df["X"]==1) & (df['Flag']==0))
```

Corresponding option

```
cond=[df['Value'],df['last_value']]

df['High']=np.select([c1,c2], cond, np.nan)
```

Fillna in the HIGH column by forward fill

```
df['High']=df.groupby('id')['High'].fillna(method='ffill')
df
```